# dcast in R to get a specific multi-column output

Tags: r, plyr, dcast

I have a data frame as follows:

```
     HR_CI algorithm value                     L1        pvalue
1 1 (1-1)        xfh  0.79            ROI_Maximum   p-value.xfh
2 1 (1-1)      xflab  0.79            ROI_Maximum p-value.xflab
3 1 (1-1)       x40p  0.70            ROI_Maximum  p-value.x40p
4 1 (1-1)        xfh  0.44 ROI_Standard_Deviation   p-value.xfh
5 1 (1-1)      xflab  0.48 ROI_Standard_Deviation p-value.xflab
6 1 (1-1)       x40p  0.45 ROI_Standard_Deviation  p-value.x40p
```

I want it to cast in such a way that L1 forms the ID column, algorithm and pvalue both swing (3 variables under pvalue and 3 algorithm). the values to be put under the 3 new columns by swing pvalue come from column 'value' and the values that go under 3 new columns by swinging algorithm should come from column HR_CI.

I have tried the following

```
 survtab <- dcast(tmp,L1~algorithm+pvalue,value.var=c("HR_CI","value"))
```

but it gives me an error

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: You need to create a sequence columns as there are duplicate entries i.e. `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(tmp), L1+rowid(L1)~algorithm + pvalue, value.var = c("HR_CI", "value"))`

Comment: It is from the devel version of `data.table`.  If you have other versions, `setDT(tmp)[, N := 1:.N, L1]; dcast(tmp, L1+N ~ algorithm, ...`